# Should React delete component if i set {key} to null?

Tags: reactjs

I heard that react auto deletes component if we manual set key to null value and it remounts component if key changes. I have tried to recreate this behavior, but failed. Here is a quick example:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Input from "./Input";
import TestKey from "./testKey";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
 
  testKeyId = "some-value-for-testing";

  nullKey = () => {
    this.testKeyId = null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TestKey key={this.testKeyId} />
        <button onClick={this.nullKey}>Destroy component</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would highly appreciate any advice on my topic.

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions if they were helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't delete the component if the `key` property will set to `null`.

`key={null}` is just another key like `key={'unique-key'}` and generating `child.key === ".$null"`

But, components with same *keys* **may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted**.

Here is an example of duplicating a component with the same key:

```js
  console.log(
    React.Children.toArray(children)
      .filter(child => child.type === NullableComponent)
      .map(child => child.key)
  );
```

Here on each render we logging the components keys.
Before turning the component key to `null` it may log:

```js
[".$unique-key-1", ".$unique-key-2"]
```

But after duplicating components keys, you can see a duplicated component with log:

```js
[".$null", ".$null"]
```

Try and change `SAME_KEY` variable to anything you want to and see that there is no difference between `null` and other key.

Also, you get the warning:

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `null`.
>   Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity
>   across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated
>   and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a
>   future version.
>       in NullableChildren (created by App)
>       in App

[image: Edit Null Key]

Answer (score 0):

You can manage a state that contains a boolean, for example, that decides if the component will be turned on or off, and a ternary operation to render it or not based on the current state:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Input from "./Input";
import TestKey from "./testKey";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      turnState: true,
    }
  }

  testKeyId = "some-value-for-testing";

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({turnState: false})
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.turnState ? <TestKey key={this.testKeyId} /> : undefined}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Destroy component</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This happens because in React, when you change a state, it will rerender all components that uses that specific state. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Yes, i know about this behavior. But my question was not about about state

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you just wanted to hide the element but was having difficulties to find a way to do that